# Set text direction for QLabel?

Tags: qt, qlabel

Is there a way to set the text direction for a QLabel? I've got a situation in which I have QLabel objects whose text is only punctuation, and I want that to be displayed either in RTL or LTR format. (For instance, parentheses or quotation marks need to reverse depending on the text direction.) I've tried calling QLabel::setLayoutDirection, but to no effect.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    QLabel label(" :  «");
    label.setFont( QFont("Times New Roman", 72) );
    label.setLayoutDirection( Qt::RightToLeft );
    // label.setLayoutDirection( Qt::LeftToRight );
    label.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

A workaround at this point is to prepend 0x202E ("Right-to-Left Override") to the string, but that's obviously a bit clunky.

Comment: You need to set text to right or to automatically transform a label with the text `abcd` to `dcba`?

Comment: @luliu your example is incorrect since `abcd` has well defined text direction.

Comment: did you tried change locale of widget?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the following with no result: label.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale::Arabic, QLocale::Egypt));

Answer (score 1):

```
label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
```

Comment: `setAlignment()` was the correct answer for me! ... as `setLayoutDirection()` does not work at all.